# Механизм взаимодействия EJB сервера и HTML/JS клиента

Tags: java, html, клиент-сервер, ejb

При разработке Java-клиента для EJB сервера, где работает наша веб-служба, не возникает трудностей с низкоуровневыми операциями механизма передачи-приема данных. 
А если клиент пишем на HTML с JavaScript, там можно делать запросы нашей веб-службе?

Comment: Туманно-поставленный вопрос :(

Если в вашем понятии веб-служба подразумевает набор EJB компонент поднятых на application сервере, то использовать их вы сможете в случае, если вы воспользуетесь каким-то java web-framework'ом или технологиями jsp/servlet. Web-framework и jsp позволяют использовать ejb напрямую, а используя сервлеты можно написать прослойку, которая будет реагировать на http запросы. ваш клиент делает http запрос к веб серверу. Запрос обрабатывается сервлетом (пример см. в ответе Антон Мухин), который в свою очередь вызывает методы EJB компонент.

Comment: Вопрос действительно некорректно поставлен. Если переформулировать: как должен быть устроен клиент и сервер, чтобы клиент HTML/JS мог делать запросы к нему?  
Простой пример: на странице клиента расположен combobox, клиент запрашивает у сервера список значений для его заполнения.

Comment: @ildar, Наиболее верно, не добавлять комментарий, а изменять текст вопроса.

Comment: Учту в дальнейшем. Вопрос не редактировал, чтобы уже добавленные комментарии не теряли смысл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. При помощи сервлетов. В файле `web.xml` пишете примерно следующее:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoaderServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- Указываем место класса-сервлета -->
    <servlet-class>works.servlets.LoaderServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <!-- это название сервлета  -->
    <servlet-name>LoaderServlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- Тут непосредственно URL, который будет вызвыать наш сервлет -->
        <url-pattern>/getTree</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Наш ЛодырьСервлет

```
public class LoaderServlet extends HttpServlet {
@EJB
private CategoryManager categoryManager;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        /*
            Все, что угодно. Теперь
            мы имеем проинъекченную некоторую переменную.
            Делаем все, что угодно.
        */
        //Вот пример забора информации из запроса от Http-клиента
        String xaction = request.getParameter("xaction");
        //Ну, теперь в xaction отправленный от клиента параметр xaction
    }
```

В результате, все `Http`-запросы на `getTree` будут вызывать сервлет.

*UPD1*:
 Исправил листинг в сервлете. Отправлять на сервер обычными методами, или необычными. как вам угодно.

Comment: Если правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Только это не совсем веб-служба.. хотя и можно из сервлета конечно веб-сервис сделать, но тяжко. С другой стороны, вопрос поставлен как-то запутанно, так что чёрт знает что требуется на самом деле.

Comment: Вопрос правильно понят, не могли бы еще показать, как на клиенте должны делаться запросы?

Comment: Обычным аяксом через XMLHttpRequest или с помощью библиотек наподобие jquery.

Comment: Пример есть.

Comment: С какими типами данных можно работать? String, int, double понятно, а массивы, объекты?

Comment: С любыми данными, которые можно закодировать текстом. Понятное дело, что String, int, double, массивы, etc передать проще, чем сложные структуры, но, можно всё. Испльзовать можно как XML или JSON, так и придумать что-то самостоятельно.